# Sidebar all messed up

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Under the couple browsers I happen to have, the sidebar with the Ad look severely horked up with text running into the ad and/or the chat thing.  Happened after forced refreshes, and in any case in browsers I rarely use.

- Chrome 10

  > [image]
- FF 4.0

  > [image]
- IE 8

  > [image]

Comment: If you rarely use all of the browsers you show here, then what *do* you use?

Comment: I didn't say 'all'.

Comment: Then you should clean up your grammar because that's how it reads with the sentences that you wrote.

Comment: @Charles No, it may be a little ambiguous but it doesn't say what you understood it as.  It's also irrelevant.  I see this on Chrome 10 as well, which is my main browser.

Comment: @Matthew - it's ambiguous because the grammatical structure of the sentence is quite poor. I never said it was relevant, I just said that it was not clear what he was saying.

Comment: @Charles - It was pretty clear to me that it wasn't ALL of the browsers. Could be IE9, FF 3.5, Safari, Opera etc.

Answer (score 1):

The fix will be in the next deployment

Comment: Looks fixed now